# Best practice for storing data in Realm on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Say I have an Image model that stores x, y, width, height, and a thumbnail, then should I store the actual image data with a `data: Data` property or store a `filePath: String` and save the image data to disk? If storing in a Data var, from doc `Data is only read when the properties are accessed` so I assume the data is not loaded to memory directly; when reading the data property, is it the same underlying action as if we are reading from a filePath or would it be faster?

Also for smaller sized thumbnail what would be the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general (not just Realm), it is not a good practice to store binary data such as images in a database. Because binary data is not able to query or sort, So there are no advantages to use databases. It is a better practice to save the file path rather than binary data in most cases.

Comment: Thanks - good to know that storing it in Realm won't give any benefits :)